# Data Link Escapes and Other Nonprintable Characters

Tags: coldfusion, sublimetext3, control-characters

In a while going through a .cfc file with a sublime text editor, I noticed that 3 characters in a string were highlighted. These characters were "DLE", and the group was treated as one character. I cannot highlight one without highlighting all of them. After doing some research, I believe this is a representation of a [Data Link Escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) in Sublime. I asked my coworker how he did it, but unfortunately he forgot. It doesn't appear to be an alt code, because alt 16 (the decimal 16 is a Data Link Escape in Ascii) appears as a triangle in sublime. If the string is printed, the "DLE" character looks like this: ┼

I can copy the "DLE" Character, but I do not know how to make one "from scratch".

How is it possible to represent a Data Link Escape in this way in sublime? Can other non print characters be shown/used in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general these can be created with the `chr()` function. It is useful for creating many the non printable characters. One of the more common usages is to crea

See: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Chr

As for DLE, you can

```
<cfset DLE = chr(16)>
```

Another common usage is to create Carriage Return / Line Feed

```
<cfset CRLF = Chr(13) & Chr(10)>
```